# Error while installing react-google-login

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-google-login

Im trying to install the react-google-login package in my application and i get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: reactjs-training@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16 || ^17" from react-google-login@5.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-google-login
npm ERR!   react-google-login@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I´ve tried running the following line:

```
 npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

But the error still persists.

Any hint or idea why am i getting this error?

Im using npm v8.6.0

Comment: Not sure what more hint you want then the error message itself... ? It's pretty clear. `react-google-login` is old an out of date. If you want to use it you will need to go with react 16/17 and force all packages that want to use react 18 to downgrade or remove them from your project as well.

Answer (score 4):

The Google Sign-In JavaScript Platform Library has been discontinued. You should use the new Google Identity Services for the web

Use this instead:

**React OAuth2 | Google**

```
npm i @react-oauth/google
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google

Answer (score 3):

**run :**

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps and
```

**then :**

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

after these you can simply run `npm i react-google-login`
but you should know that react-google-login is kind of deprecated and not suitalble for react 18

Answer (score 1):

force install package with npm or use yarn like this:

```
npm install react-google-login --force
```

or

```
yarn add react-google-login
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The following worked for me:

```
npm install react-google-login --force
```